# Where to find a good database (factory) class with connectionpooling?

Tags: database, vb.net, connection-pooling, factory, data-access

I found a lot of information about how to make a database factory or how to deal with connection pooling but i nowhere found a complete solution.

I have always used my own solutions, but they're not complete i think or could be improved.

Are there some good designed classes any of you use that i can find on the net?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: I would argue that if they do what you need, and do it reliably, they are complete enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think probably the best example of this would be the [`DatabaseFactory`](http://entlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/59326#770887) class that is found within Microsoft's own [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/).

It's available from the Codeplex site and comes with full source code.  The downside is that the code is in C# rather than VB.NET.  It does, however, offer a `DatabaseFactory` class (amongst others) that represent best practise approaches to these programming areas.

Bear in mind that the [Enterprise Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Enterprise_Library) will use System.Data namespace classes and so can take advantage of any "built-in" connection pooling available (for example when connecting to SQL Server and using the same connection string).